# how can i still get this problem after i mention the service in the manifest

Tags: java, android, service, module, android-manifest

I'm trying to run a service from another module but event i have declared this service in the Manifest, I still get an exception 
in the module app.mainifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="test.OFIE">
       .
       .
       .
<application ....>
       .
       .
       .
       .
<service android:name="zdi.pak.xmlmmi.Service_libs.PlayerService"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

But i still have this exeption:

```
W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {test.OFIE/zdi.pak.xmlmmi.Service_libs.PlayerService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 2):

It's declared as a service. You are probably calling this with startActivity(new Intent(this, Service.class). Since there's no activity declared as that class hence the error.